# Max/min attributes in bootstrap-ui timepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use the [timepicker directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker) from bootstrap-ui. I need to use the `min` and `max` attributes, but I don't understand how to use them.

I tried to use it on the range from 0 to 1440.

```
<uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" show-meridian="false" min="840" max="1020"></uib-timepicker>
```

I also tried to pass different date formats, but it doesn't solve my issue. For example, I need user can set timepicker from 14:00 to 17:00. How can I achieve this effect with these attributes?

You can find a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LEFR8UiaVhXqc40wGL3P?p=preview) here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `min` and `max` values in `controller` itself:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours( 2 );
d.setMinutes( 0 );
$scope.min = d;

var d2 = new Date();
d2.setHours( 11 );
d2.setMinutes( 0 );
$scope.max = d2;
```

And use them,

```
<uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" min="min" max="max" show-meridian="false"></uib-timepicker>
```

here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mpLVj8G0d3DeAmaDQaYy?p=preview)

Comment: Can you post a plunker?

Comment: @TurakVladyslav created

Comment: in the plunker the min and max doesnt seem to work..or am I missing something?

Comment: The plunker is incomplete. Simply add `min="min" max="max"` to the uib-timepicker in the HTML.